# PermGen settings not taking effect

Tags: java, maven, permgen

I'm trying to increase the amount of PermGen space my application has to avoid some PermGen errors.

I've tried exporting both JAVA_OPTS and MAVEN_OPTS as

```
-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled  -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
```

But jconsole still shows the "CMS Perm Gen" maximum to be:

```
Max: 83,968 kbytes
```

and the application still runs out of PermGen space when it hits this.

Comment: how do you launch your application ?

Comment: mvn install - within this, as part of one of the acceptance tests, the application is loaded into a new Tomcat instance and tested against

Comment: then you probably need to change the settings for whatever is forking off the tomcat instance.  most likely the relevant plugin has some sort of "jvm args" config you can manipulate.

Comment: I'm not doing it via a plugin - the Tomcat instance is started in code with e.g 'Tomcat tomcatServer = new org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat()'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried adding those options to your pom - under the surefire plugin configuration as you have to tell surefire about these opts explicitly

```
<argLine>-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled</argLine>
```

Answer (score 3):

According your comments you are starting something like cargo plugin. You need to look at the cargo plugin configuration to pass additional VM args, or directly in the script launching tomcat.

The JAVA_OPTS are applied to the launched app when using maven-exec-plugin with goal java